# Custom Syntax Highlighting in Sublime Text 3 – cannot convert

Tags: syntax-highlighting, sublimetext3

I am trying to create my own syntax highlighting for Sublime Text 3. The main purpose of it is to distinguish text written in Latin script from text written in Cyrillic script. I have already installed AAAPackageControl and read the [tutorial](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/syntax.html), but I cannot make it work for some reason.

Here's the syntax I wrote

```
# [PackageDev] target_format: plist, ext: tmLanguage
---
name: ADVANCED TEXT
scopeName: text.mirkowy
fileTypes: []
uuid: 78dbe755-58eb-4cdf-b954-4438334aedb9

patterns:
- comment: Words in Latin Script
  name: latin_text.text.mirkowy
  match: [A-Za-z]+
- comment: Words in Cyrillic Script
  name: cyrillic_text.text.mirkowy
  match: [ЁЂЃЄЅІЇЈЉЊЋЌЎЏАБВГДЕЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯабвгдежзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюяёђѓєѕіїјљњћќўџҐґ]+
- comment: Numbers
  name: numbers.text.mirkowy
  match: \d
...
```

However, when I press F7 to convert that file to plist, I keep getting and error and I don't understand why (bear in mind that I am completely new to creating one's own syntaxes and the like) — here's what it looks like:

```
Input type not specified, auto-detecting... YAML
No target format specified, searching in file... Property List
Parsing YAML... (C:\Users\iyoossaev\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages\User\mirkowy.YAML-tmLanguage)
Error parsing YAML: while parsing a block mapping
```

What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost got it, but there is a minor issue with your regexes - character classes surrounded by square brackets `[ ]` need to be within parentheses `( )`. Your "Numbers" regex `\d` works fine without parens. So, just change your code to the following:

```
# [PackageDev] target_format: plist, ext: tmLanguage
---
name: ADVANCED TEXT
scopeName: text.mirkowy
fileTypes: []
uuid: 78dbe755-58eb-4cdf-b954-4438334aedb9

patterns:
- comment: Words in Latin Script
  name: latin_text.text.mirkowy
  match: ([A-Za-z]+)

- comment: Words in Cyrillic Script
  name: cyrillic_text.text.mirkowy
  match: ([ЁЂЃЄЅІЇЈЉЊЋЌЎЏАБВГДЕЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯабвгдежзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюяёђѓєѕіїјљњћќўџҐґ]+)

- comment: Numbers
  name: numbers.text.mirkowy
  match: \d
```

and you should be all set. Note that I put a blank space between each block - it's not required, but it helps you visually separate each block, which comes in very useful when you get very complicated blocks.

If you'd like some examples of more complex `.YAML-tmLanguage` syntax definitions, two places come immediately to mind. The first is the [`Syntax Definitions`](https://github.com/SublimeText/PackageDev/tree/master/Syntax%20Definitions) folder in the `PackageDev` package itself. The second is actually in a personal project of mine, the [`Python Improved`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Python%20Improved) syntax definition which aims to be a much better replacement for the built-in Python syntax that ships with Sublime. You can find the source for [`PythonImproved.YAML-tmLanguage`](https://github.com/MattDMo/PythonImproved/blob/master/PythonImproved.YAML-tmLanguage) on Github. Feel free to open an [issue](https://github.com/MattDMo/PythonImproved/issues) there if you have any questions on syntax design, or just ask a new question here.

Good luck!

Comment: Indeed, it worked as suggested. Thanks for the help; I will also check out the places you have suggested :)